# changing the text of the button onclick

Tags: android

change the text of the button once clicked to P then again that same button is clicked the text should change to A then again the same button is clicked the text should change to H then again when the button is pressed the text should change to L in android Studio how c

Comment: use some switch case or if statement

Comment: please include code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work 100%

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int current = 0;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (current){
                    case 0:
                        button.setText("P");
                        current = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        button.setText("A");
                        current = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        button.setText("H");
                        current = 3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        button.setText("L");
                        current = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch (curr) {
                case 0:
                    button.setText("P");
                    curr = curr + 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button.setText("A");
                    curr = curr + 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    button.setText("H");
                    curr = curr + 1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    button.setText("L");
                    curr = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: when i press once then P comes but second time when i press nothing happends

Comment: declare curr out of onClick scop

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need three things for this:

1. A way to react to the button being clicked
2. A way to set and get the state of the button
3. A way to change the text on the button

Thankfully, these are all easy tasks.

To react to a button click, set its OnClickListener

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        updateButtonState();
    }
});
```

To set and get the state of the button, we need a way of representing the state. Since you described a simple state of P -> A -> H -> L we can represent each point as an integer.

```
final int BUTTON_STATE_P = 0;
final int BUTTON_STATE_A = 1;
final int BUTTON_STATE_H = 2;
final int BUTTON_STATE_L = 3;
```

We can then simply store the given state into a variable change this variable according to our state logic and then read whatever value the variable is at.

```
int buttonState = BUTTON_STATE_P;

private void updateButtonState(){
    if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_P){
        buttonState = BUTTON_STATE_A;
    }
    else if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_A){
        buttonState = BUTTON_STATE_H;
    }
    else if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_H){
        buttonState = BUTTON_STATE_L;
    }
}
```

Then we just need a way of setting the text of the button depending upon what state we're in. To do this we need to know what each state looks like in terms of text.

```
button.setText(getTextForButtonState(buttonState));

private String getTextForButtonState(int buttonState){
    if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_P){
        return "P";
    }
    else if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_A){
        return "A";
    }
    else if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_H){
        return "H";
    }
    else if (buttonState == BUTTON_STATE_L){
        return "L";
    }

    return null;
}
```

You'll notice that the most important step was step 2. You can make lots of different decisions as to how you might want to handle a state. You might decide that you want to put all of your state code into its own class and then just call methods of that class, as one suggestion.

Hope this helps.